# Xrite Colorchecker color specifications and 18% reflectance gray card

Tags: color-management, white-balance, display-calibration, colorchecker

I have a Xrite Colorchecker Classic:

[image]

- Where to find the color specifications for each square (either in CMJN or any other format)?

  Let's say I want to develop my own open-source color correction software (that can use a color checker), then these reference numbers would be necessary.
- Also, which square of the bottom row is equivalent to a [18% gray card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_card)?

  > A gray card is a flat object of a neutral gray color that derives from a flat reflectance spectrum. A typical example is the Kodak R-27 set, which contains two 8x10" cards and one 4x5" card which have 18% reflectance across the visible spectrum, and a white reverse side which has 90% reflectance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official specifications are available on X-Rite website at this URL: https://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?ID=938&Action=Support&SupportID=5884. The specifications have changed in November 2014, hence the two sets.

They are given in [CIE Lab](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L*a*b*_CIE_1976) and the white point is [CIE Illuminant D Series D50](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminant) with the following [CIE XYZ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_XYZ) values: `[96.42, 100.00, 82.49]` as given by [ICC](http://www.color.org/whyd50.xalter).

Example: in the case of November 2014 Colorchecker Classic, here it is:

```
ColorChecker24_After_Nov2014.txt
################################

LGOROWLENGTH 12                     
ORIGINATOR "ColorChecker24 - November2014 edition and newer"
MANUFACTURER "X-Rite - http://www.xrite.com"                

4/28/2015  # Time: 14:33            
"i1Pro 2 ; Serial number 1001785"           
"MeasurementCondition=M0    Filter=no"      

NUMBER_OF_FIELDS 4                      
BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT                       
SAMPLE_NAME Lab_L   Lab_a   Lab_b                       
END_DATA_FORMAT                     
NUMBER_OF_SETS 24                       
BEGIN_DATA                      
A1  37,54   14,37   14,92
A2  62,73   35,83   56,5
A3  28,37   15,42   -49,8
A4  95,19   -1,03   2,93
B1  64,66   19,27   17,5
B2  39,43   10,75   -45,17
B3  54,38   -39,72  32,27
B4  81,29   -0,57   0,44
C1  49,32   -3,82   -22,54
C2  50,57   48,64   16,67
C3  42,43   51,05   28,62
C4  66,89   -0,75   -0,06
D1  43,46   -12,74  22,72
D2  30,1    22,54   -20,87
D3  81,8    2,67    80,41
D4  50,76   -0,13   0,14
E1  54,94   9,61    -24,79
E2  71,77   -24,13  58,19
E3  50,63   51,28   -14,12
E4  35,63   -0,46   -0,48
F1  70,48   -32,26  -0,37
F2  71,51   18,24   67,37
F3  49,57   -29,71  -28,32
F4  20,64   0,07    -0,46
END_DATA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Something I don't understand (it's the same in your answer and mine) @KelSolaar: the black square (bottom right square) of the Colorchecker should be L*a*b(20.64,0.07,-0.46), i.e. ... ~ RGB(50, 50, 50), i.e. this color: https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/323232! This is definitely **not** what we want for the darkest black in a photo, it's too light! What do you think about this mystery?

Comment: The bottom right square is not really meant not represent the darkest black in a photo, merely something with low reflectance, charcoal, Vantablack or MIT's Blackest Black. However, it is part of the bottom row which is a perceptually uniform gradient and is super helpful to assess non-uniformity of the lighting.

Answer (score 8):

After further research, here is a partial answer taking as source [Blog-Couleur: Quelles sont les valeurs RVB de la colorchecker ?](http://www.blog-couleur.com/?Quelles-sont-les-valeurs-RVB-de-la) and [BabelColor PDF](http://www.babelcolor.com/index_htm_files/RGB%20Coordinates%20of%20the%20Macbeth%20ColorChecker.pdf) and the Xrite website.

- The last row seems to be white 95%, neutral 80%, neutral 65%, neutral 50%, neutral 35%, black 20%.

  > On trouve entre le blanc et le noir, une série de 4 gris : neutral 0.35, neutral 0.50, neutral 0.65 et neutral 0.80. Le neutral 0.50 de luminosité 50 % est le fameux gris moyen de luminance 18 %.

  Thus, **the fourth square of the last row seems to be the 50% neutral gray (18% reflectance) of a [gray card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_card)**. In sRGB, it should be close to RGB(119,119,119) according to some sources (color #777777 in hex) or RGB(122,122,121) or RGB(121,121,122) according to other sources.

  More about this [here](http://www.blog-couleur.com/modale/middle-grey.htm).
- More generally, the website [BabelColor](http://www.babelcolor.com/colorchecker.htm) / Danny Pascale gives a lot of data (RGB, L*a*b) related to various versions of Colorchecker:

  [image]
- [Here (PDF)](https://xritephoto.com/documents/literature/en/ColorData-1p_EN.pdf) is the data given by Xrite themselves:

  [image]

Comment: "The code value of 118 in an 8-bit system corresponds to 18% of the maximum final output for sRGB." - ISO 12232, 3rd edition, 2019-02 "Photography — Digital still cameras — Determination of exposure index, ISO speed ratings, standard output sensitivity, and recommended exposure index", page 11.